# I switched to a Debian desktop, how can I download my notes from Ubuntu One acct?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, debian, tomboy

I have Tomboy Notes on my Debian desktop. I would like to download my backed up notes at my Ubuntu One acct.  I can login, but don't know how to download all my notes (about 80)

I don't need to make Ubuntu One run on Debian, I just need to make Tomboy download and also sync with my Ubuntu One account. Can it be done ?

I appreciate any help or advice you can share.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are running Tomboy 1.0.1 or greater. 1.2.2-2 is the version in Testing and Unstable currently. It will also be the version included in the next release of Debian Stable.

This version should support on-line sync. Ubuntu patches Tomboy to use U1 by default, but sync is supported upstream. Open Tomboy's preferences and goto the synchronization tab. If "Ubuntu One" is not available in the "Service" list, select Tomboy Web. Then enter `https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/` for the "Server."

[image: tomboy]

Comment: You shouldn't need 1.5.2 for sync.  1.0.1 or greater should work.  1.4.x is the current stable series.

Comment: I suppose I should trust the upstream developer. Fixed above. Thanks Sandy.